# Android How to Display Links in webview like this?

Tags: android, url, webview

Does anyone know of a way to Display URL's in webview like this

[image]

But here I am geting Like this  here no focus and no click option not working any thing give me some sugessions please..

[image]

this code useing display data in webview

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, string, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: The text which is shown in the webview is of String format??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String str="Your text goes here... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576507/android-how-to-display-links-in-webview-like-this`";

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

myArray.add( "<!DOCTYPE HTML><!-- created HTML PAGE -->");
myArray.add("<head> ");
myArray.add("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"  width=100%>");
myArray.add("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">");
myArray.add("<style>");
myArray.add("   p { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}");
myArray.add("</style>");
myArray.add("</head> ");
myArray.add("<body style=\"background-color: transparent; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; \">");

myArray.add("<div >");
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(str);
Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
str = Html.toHtml(sp) ;
myArray.add(str);

String myFullString = myArray.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "\n").replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">");

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", myFullString ,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy.P i have written link in ` ` so that you get to copy the exact code as it is... and then you can check for yourself if the code is working or not...

Comment: did you try replacing the content of **str** variable with your data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23545/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-p-and-pallavi)

Comment: if use this way,when u embed something not in [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) list,it will remove all that tags

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).

```
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(string));
Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
final String html = "<body>" + Html.toHtml(sp) + "</body>";
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: In that String Value i have image url in that url not display in image in webview....

Comment: A WebView will display only HTML content. Simply having an image URL will not show the image. You have to build an HTML with img tags. This, however, is not what your original question is.

Comment: i am set in image url in html format that html string pass to `SpannableString(string)` here paramater String is html String in this except image url all are working.

Comment: if use this way,when u embed something not in [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) list,it will remove all that tags

Comment: Its ignore to Linkifya href=\"https://testurl_09u7ymNi01bNpDXfY1A?e=rBZ2N8\" target=\"_blank\">

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

Java:

```
 TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
 t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

android:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/yourid"
android:id="@+id/yourid"
android:layout_below="@+id/yourid" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></TextView>
```

[Android WebView: Change Auto-Link Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829247/android-webview-change-auto-link-display) for webview

Comment: I added link into my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  String header = "< ?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
  String data = "< html>< body>< a href='tel:555-5599'>508-776-5510
  " "< /body>< /html>";
  mWebView.loadData(header+data,  "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

If you are loading a string of html texts into webView then you can use:

```
mWebView.loadData(header+data,  "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

If you have an html file then you can use:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html"):
```

**Note:** Dont forget to put your html file in your assets folder.

Cheers!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Please Add android:autoLink="web" in your TextView

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:autoLink="web"  
        android:textColorLink="@color/link"
        android:text="click here to load www.fb.com"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```