# how can i get the url of a hyperlink in android webview without opening the link

Tags: android, webview, tag-cloud

I have made a `WebView` with some words showing as tags, these tags must be clickable so that after clicking a tag, a list of related content in new page is shown to the user. for this purpose i have put the words in hyperlinks of `WebView`. I need to get the text inside each tag "a" after clicking the hyperlink. But defining `webviewclient` for the `WebView` dosen't work. 
here is my main activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] wordCloud = new String[]{"Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb",
            "Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat", "Lollipop", "Marshmallow"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView d3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.d3);



        WebSettings ws = d3.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String span = "";
        String html = "<HTML><head>\n" +
                "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=no\">\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < wordCloud.length; i++) {
            span = span + "<span  data-weight=\"" + 5 + "\" >" + wordCloud[i] + "</span><a href=\"example.com/tags/"+wordCloud[i] +"\">"+ wordCloud[i] +"</a><br/>\n";
        }
        html= html +span +
                "<span  data-weight=\"6\" > some example </span><br/>\n" +
                "</body></HTML>";

        d3.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");


        d3.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                String[] parts = url.split("/");
                String tag=parts[2];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }


        });


    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use the SpannableString  , for info refer this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42671603/3946958

Comment: thanks for your comment, the problem is that each tag has an indivisual weight. In fact i'm trying to make a tagCloud with javascript which is loaded in webview and i need the tags to be clickable ;(

Comment: Means inside the Webview , u want to clickable tag?

Comment: yes exactly, i have some tags which should be loaded by webview, now i need these tags to be clickable and i can get the tag's text.

Comment: Refer this solution  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14576752/3946958  , it might help u

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to test this solution :)

Comment: thank you @RavindraKushwaha , you solved my problem :)